# Using pandas to read text file with leading whitespace gives a NaN column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am using pandas.read_csv to read a whitespace delimited file. The file has a variable number of whitespace characters in front of every line (the numbers are right-aligned). When I read this file, it creates a column of NaN. Why does this happen, and what is the best way to prevent it?

Example:

Text file:

```
  9.0  3.3 4.0
 32.3 44.3 5.1
  7.2  1.1 0.9
```

Command:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("test.txt",delim_whitespace=True,header=None)
```

Output:

```
    0     1     2    3
0 NaN   9.0   3.3  4.0
1 NaN  32.3  44.3  5.1
2 NaN   7.2   1.1  0.9
```

Comment: It looks like someone has [opened up an issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3374) based upon this post:

Answer (score 16, accepted):

FWIW I tend to use `\s+` instead, and it doesn't suffer the same problem:

```
>>> pd.read_csv("wspace.csv", header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
    0     1     2    3
0 NaN   9.0   3.3  4.0
1 NaN  32.3  44.3  5.1
2 NaN   7.2   1.1  0.9
>>> pd.read_csv("wspace.csv", header=None, sep=r"\s+")
      0     1    2
0   9.0   3.3  4.0
1  32.3  44.3  5.1
2   7.2   1.1  0.9
```

Comment: Interesting that this would be different (I too use `'\s+'`), surely a bug?

Comment: We shouldn't need to use `'\s+'`. [The relevant pandas tutorial page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) says that `delim_whitespace=True` is supposed to be faster.

I'll wait for any other responses that might explain this, but likely will tag this as my solution.

Comment: This is a pretty ambiguous case for `delim_whitespace`. It's not clear to me what's the right behavior-- `'\s+'` is working essentially "by accident" as AFAICT.

Comment: @WesMcKinney: hmm.  I was about to propose something but then I thought of counterexamples.  I actually switched to using `sep` again precisely because of this behaviour a while ago.  If the two are supposed to have the same behaviour then that should be fixed, at least, so I can start dropping columns where necessary.  I'm not sure whether an `ignore_leading_delimiter` is the right way to go or not.

Comment: Not sure what `ignore_leading_delimiter` is. Don't see it [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html). Do you mean `skipinitialspace=True`? That doesn't seem to change the NaN behaviour.

Comment: @Caleb: no, that's something I was considering proposing (i.e. would be the right way to go or not.)

Comment: @DSM Ah, I see.  It seems to me that if you are using whitespace delimiters, then it will almost always be wrong to try and read leading whitespace as an element. In other words, I think the current behavior is bad. However, `ignore_leading_delimiter` might be useful for other delimiters. Something like `skip_initial_whitespace` might be useful in such cases also.

Comment: These comments were all very helpful. I was importing separate chunks of a file (some of the data from Ken French's data library) and using the delim_whitespace was causing an error when increasing the number of rows from 999 to 1000. I switched to the sep and it works. Not sure why delim doesn't work, but I don't trust it for now.